# Display Fusion & SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: windows, windows-7, ssms, monitors

When opening SQL Server Management Studio 2008 using Display Fusion on Windows 7 with multi-monitor, the software opens, but doesn't display the 'New Server Connection' window, and then I can't close SSMS apart from ending the task on Windows Task Manager.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, and how can I resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out what the problem is here. The connection dialog window does appear, but its off screen (at the top). So by unplugging the monitor cable (so you're running on one monitor), the connection dialog box is reset to the centre of the screen.